# In CKAN how do I list all the dataset resources with a table / entry in the DataStore?

Tags: datastore, ckan

In CKAN how do I list all the dataset resources with a table / entry in the DataStore?

That is, put a different way, can I find out what dataset resources have data loaded into the DataStore?

Also can I just list all the entries / tables in the DataStore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a special view `_table_metadata` that contains all tables and views in the datastore. Although, it is mainly used for internally, it can also be used to get a full list of all datastore resources.

Example call: http://demo.ckan.org/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=_table_metadata

See the [docs for details about the `_table_metadata` view](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/datastore.html#internal-structure-of-the-database).